# How can I make my Imessage stickers being available to be used in whatsapp

Tags: ios, whatsapp, imessage

I would like to know if it is possible to share the Imessage stickers in whatsapp. If it is possible how can I code the app for that?

Comment: @Oliver, I can help you with this. let me know if you still need an ios dev.

Comment: @i.AsifNoor  I can hire you on freelancer or upwork to do this for me.

Comment: @Oliver,yeah that can work.you can search me with email id conzapps@gmail.com or send me email at asef.noor@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to build a separate keyboard extension with the stickers so that in WhatsApp they will be sent as images or GIFs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is this code open source?

Comment: Watch part 1 and two of this talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/204/

Comment: Swift or objective c

Comment: What do you mean by is it open source?

Comment: Swift is an open-source project

Comment: I know but I am asking you if you are interested to use swift or objective c to write the separate keyboard extension. I ll hire you on www.upwork.com

Comment: I usually write my apps in Swift

Comment: Swift is great! It s better than objective c. So are you interested?

Comment: It s a website where freelancers can work for employers. I am an employer. I can hire you.

Comment: Well, I would like but I'm not 18 years old yet.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks though for the insight! :)

Comment: Anytime. I guess I should be 18 to be hired on upwork, right?

Comment: I think so but I m not sure

Comment: @user6603599 And what if I want to use sticker pack's stickers inside my app..which is not using keyboard but the images/stickers? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @iRiziya can you explain, please?

Answer (score 4):

Download sample project and required files from GitHub:
https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/iOS

Then create a sticker pack using below code:

```
let stickerPack = StickerPack(identifier: "identifier",
name: "sticker pack name", 
publisher: "sticker pack publisher", 
trayImageFileName: "tray image file name", 
publisherWebsite: "publisher website URL", 
privacyPolicyWebsite: "privacy policy website URL", 
licenseAgreementWebsite: "license agreement website URL")
```

Add stickers to sticker pack:

```
stickerPack.addSticker(contentsOfFile: "file name of sticker image", 
emojis: ["array of emojis"])
```

Call below method to import your sticker pack to Whatsapp:

```
stickerPack.sendToWhatsApp { completed in
// Called when the sticker pack has been wrapped in a form that WhatsApp 
// can read and WhatsApp is about to open.
}
```

You have to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Also, There is some limitations and predefined syntax you have to use,
Read more about creating whatsapp stickers:

https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000226

Comment: @Filnor & widjajjayd Thanks for suggestion, i will surely update my answer later with context of actual answer.